# SEO images with 301 redirect

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, images, google-image-search, google-website-optimizer

We all know that it is a best practice to use images like *samsung-galaxy-s6.jpg* instead of *img01231.jpg*.

But, what if I'll use an image like

```
http://www.example.com/img/samsung-galaxy-s6.jpg
```

that made a 301 redirect to

```
http://cdn.sito.com/i/m/g/img01231.jpg
```

Is it the same?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an _internal rewrite_, but not if you are rewriting to an entirely different domain (ie. your CDN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not same. Google will count `img01231` as `<ALT>` or `<title>` name for new image. Basically 301 redirect passes link juice not such things.